# Load image mouseclick - Processing / Java

Tags: java, processing

I am trying to write simple code (my first few hours using Processing and Java) that will display a negative image similar to Rubin's Vase. The, are there 2 face or one vase one?

I have the code which loads the first image (black faces / white vase).

```
    PImage img;
void setup () {
  size (1000, 480);
 img = loadImage ("vaseedit.jpg");
}

void draw () {
  background(180,180,180);
  image(img,0,0);
}
```

How can I get the second image to load on a mouse click? I have tried, but not got close to achieving

a) one click 2nd image appears. another click it disappears and so on

b) display second image whilst mouse button is held down

The closest I have got with code for switching images, but it won't run, is

```
PImage img,imageinverse;
void setup () {
  size (1000, 480);
 img = loadImage ("vaseedit.jpg");
 imageinverse = loadImage ("vaseeditinverse.jpg");

 int value = 0;
}

void draw () {
  background(0,0,0);
  image(img,0,0);

}

void mousePressed () {
  if(value == 0) {
    image (imageinverse, 0,0);

  } else {

    image(img,0,0);

  }

}
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on Stack Overflow. See ["Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there. For future reference, you should always include the exact text of any errors you encounter, as well as which lines they're on.

Notice that you declare the value variable inside the setup() function, so it goes **out of scope** as soon as the setup function exits. Read a tutorial about scope [here](http://staticvoidgames.com/tutorials/basicConcepts/scope).

You also never change the value variable. So even if you declared the value variable at the top of the sketch so it's still **in scope** in your mousePressed() function, that if statement will always evaluate to true. Learn more about modifying variables over time [here](http://staticvoidgames.com/tutorials/basicConcepts/animation).

Even if you fix those two issues, the mousePressed() function is only called once per mouse click, as soon as you press the button. So when you press the mouse, you're drawing an image. However, you're also drawing an image in your draw() function, which is called 60 times per second. That means that you draw an image when the mouse is pressed, but then 1/60th of a second later, you draw a different image over top of it.

Instead, try simply setting the value variable in your mousePressed() function, then refer to that variable from your draw() function to decide which image to draw.

Here's a small example that does that to decide which color to draw:

```
int value = 0;

void draw(){
  if(value == 0){
    background(0, 0, 0);
  }
  else if(value == 1){
    background(255, 0, 0);
  }
  else if(value == 2){
    background(0, 255, 0);
  }
}

void mousePressed(){

  //increment the value variable
  value = value + 1;

  //reset the value variable when it gets too big
  if(value > 2){
    value = 0;
  }
}
```